# What is the reason that this question is considered as 'off-topic'?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, closed-questions

I posted the below question, and there were a couple of helpful answers.

[Is 'dead on arrival' a slang?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/596623/is-dead-on-arrival-a-slang)

As of now, this question has been closed as an 'off-topic' question.

https://english.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

I carefully read the above post but still don't understand the reason that this question was considered off-topic. Could anybody explain this?

Comment: As usual it's hard to know the inner motivations of individuals, those close voting. I don't see why this was closed. Note you can vote to reopen your own closed question.

Comment: Yay! It was voted enough to reopen!

Comment: [correction: a slang term]

Comment: @Lambie Thanks. You are right.